# How to decompose number into sum of powers of 3 with coefficients from set {-1,0,1} (is my algorithm correct)

Tags: combinatorics

Given vector $(a_0,a_1,...,a_{18})$ where $a_i \in$ {-1,0,1} for all integer i from 0 to 18. Amount of non-zero $a_i$'s is called length of decomposition (and if it is not possible to decompose number into this from then length is -1 by definition). Decomposition of number b is $\sum_{i=0}^{18}a_i3^i$. How to compute length of decomposition of natural number b $\le 10^9$ if this decomposition exists (if not, then length is -1 by definition)?

Example: for b=61 vector is (1,-1,1,-1,1,0,0,...,0) and length is 5. For $10^9-1$ there is no such vector and length is -1.

My assumptions are that all numbers greater than $\frac {3^{19}-1}2$ have length -1, others have positive length.
Algorithm is (for each number): on i-th iteration we check if $3^{i+1}\mid(x_i\pm3^i)$ and if it's true then $a_i=\pm1$ and $a_i=0$ else, where $x_i=x_{i-1}+a_i3^i$ and $x_{-1}=b$

Is my algorithm correct and how to fix it if it's not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that a base-3 representation of an integer would result in coefficients (digits) in {0, 1, 2} i.e., residues modulo 3. Also note that $2 \equiv -1 \mod 3$.

Every integer has a unique base-$b$ representation $\forall b \in Z$. So, a base-$3$ representation exists for all integers $N$.

Now, we need a way to convert coefficients in $\{0, 1, 2\}$ into $\{-1, 0, 1\}$. Using the fact that $2 \equiv -1 \mod 3$, we can accomplish this as follows:

Let $N = a_0 + a_1 \times 3 + a_2 \times 3^2 + \dots + a_k \times 3^k + \dots + a_n$

Say, $a_1 = 2$. We write this as $a_1 = 3 - 1$.

If we replace $(3 -1)$ as the value of $a_1$ and expand the term, we get

$N = a_0 + (3-1) \times 3 + a_2 \times 3^2 + \dots + a_k \times 3^k + \dots + a_n$

$\implies a_0 + (-1) \times 3 + (1 + a_2) \times 3^2 + \dots + a_k \times 3^k + \dots + a_n$

So, whenever we encounter the digit $2$ in the base-3 representation while scanning the digits from the least significant digit onwards, we change it to $-1$ and carry $1$ to the next digit. We repeat this for all digits up to the most significant digit.

This will give us the desired representation for any natural number. To get the $Length = $ number of non-zero digits, just count them.

If the representation has $\gt 19$ digits when written in full form, $Length = -1$ as per the definition.

The algorithm can be implemented iteratively by computing the digits (standard base-$b$ conversion through repeated division and taking remainders) and calculating the carry for the next step.